# Ansible playbook for windows upgrade (not Update), issues with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible

We are trying to do a windows upgrade from ver 2016 to 2019. This setup includes to mount a trial version of iso image of 2019 using the Ansible playbook. This works fine. However to start the upgrade process, it seems to fail with one or the other error :

Some code :

```
---
- hosts: win
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Mounting ISO image file with drive
      win_shell: |
        $isoDirectory = @("C:\Windows_Server_2016_Datacenter_EVAL_en-us_14393_refresh.ISO","C:\17763.3650.221105-1748.rs5_release_svc_refresh_SERVER_EVAL_x64FRE_en-us.iso")
        $driveLetterFile = "C:\driveletter.txt"
        $osName = (Get-ComputerInfo).OsName
        Write-Host "Detected OS Name: $osName"
        # Read the stored drive letter from the file
        $storedDriveLetter = Get-Content $driveLetterFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        # If no drive letter is stored or the stored drive letter is not valid, proceed with mounting
        if (-not $storedDriveLetter -or (Get-Volume -DriveLetter $storedDriveLetter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
            foreach ($isoFile in $isoDirectory) {
                if ($osName -like '*Windows Server 2016*' -and $isoFile -like '*221105*') {
                    Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $isoFile
                    $isoImage = Get-DiskImage -ImagePath $isoFile | Get-Volume
                    $isoDrive = [string]$isoImage.DriveLetter + ":"
                    Write-Host "Mounted ISO File: $isoFile"
                    Write-Host "Mounted Volume Drive: $isoDrive"
                    # Store the mounted drive letter in the file
                    $isoDrive | Out-File -FilePath $driveLetterFile
                    break  # exit the loop once the correct ISO is mounted
                }
                elseif ($osName -like '*Windows Server 2019*' -and $isoFile -like '*2016*') {
                    Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $isoFile
                    $isoImage = Get-DiskImage -ImagePath $isoFile | Get-Volume
                    $isoDrive = [string]$isoImage.DriveLetter + ":"
                    Write-Host "Mounted ISO File: $isoFile"
                    Write-Host "Mounted Volume Drive: $isoDrive"
                    # Store the mounted drive letter in the file
                    $isoDrive | Out-File -FilePath $driveLetterFile
                    break  # exit the loop once the correct ISO is mounted
                }
            }
        } else {
            # Use the stored drive letter without mounting
            $isoDrive = $storedDriveLetter
            Write-Host "Using previously mounted Volume Drive: $isoDrive"
        }
      register: mount_status
      tags:
        - mount

    - name: Locate setup.exe file path
      win_shell: |
        $setupPath = Join-Path -Path "{{ mount_status.stdout_lines[-1].split(': ')[1] }}" -ChildPath 'setup.exe'
        Write-Output "Setup.exe Path: $setupPath"
      register: path

    - name: location of ISO image file along with executable
      debug:
        var: path.stdout_lines
      tags:
        - path

          #- name: Running setup.exe file
          #win_command: X:\setup.exe /auto upgrade /imageindex 4
      #win_command: X:\setup.exe /auto upgrade /quiet /compat ignorewarning /imageindex 4 /dynamicupdate disable
      #win_shell: |
        #$setupPath = Join-Path -Path "{{ mount_status.stdout_lines[-1].split(': ')[1] }}" -ChildPath 'setup.exe'
          #Write-Output "Path of setup.exe file: $setupPath"
          #Invoke-Expression -Command "$setupPath /copylogs upgrade /imageindex 4 -Wait"
          #Invoke-Expression -Command "$setupPath /auto upgrade /quiet /imageindex 3"
```

In which the part that is not working is (commented for now) :

```
        #- name: Running setup.exe file
          #win_command: X:\setup.exe /auto upgrade /imageindex 4
      #win_command: X:\setup.exe /auto upgrade /quiet /compat ignorewarning /imageindex 4 /dynamicupdate disable
      #win_shell: |
        #$setupPath = Join-Path -Path "{{ mount_status.stdout_lines[-1].split(': ')[1] }}" -ChildPath 'setup.exe'
          #Write-Output "Path of setup.exe file: $setupPath"
          #Invoke-Expression -Command "$setupPath /copylogs upgrade /imageindex 4 -Wait"
          #Invoke-Expression -Command "$setupPath /auto upgrade /quiet /imageindex 3"
```

All we are trying to acheive is get the setup to proceed with upgrade without human intervention.

The set of commands work on powershell directly though but not through Ansible.

we get errors like : OxC1900215, OxC190010A,0xC1900204 etc. What is the right approach through Ansible?

Also, if Ansible is a correct tool to do an Windows upgrade (not update).

Comment: Those errors are not related to Ansible at all. For example, [0xC1900204](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/20h2-error-0xc1900204/7ab5af11-81f2-4a25-974e-d0e254144cae&ved=2ahUKEwiYhYGEweaDAxW8gf0HHbHxAQYQFnoECBEQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2ZgCJPUnsi4kX9A-StvNG1) may mean that Windows update services don't run properly. Adding the whole playbook execution output may help the community to suggest a solution. I'm no expert in Windows but from what I currently see Ansible works fine here.

Comment: As @AlexanderPletnev mentioned these errors are related to windows itself. Ansible may not be the best tool for upgrades due to the issues that can happen as you can see. Error OxC1900215 indicates an issue with the command-line arguments.
Error 0xC1900204 indicates there might be an issue with the Windows Update components. If you are using SCCM or MECM now, that's probably better to use.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the image which we use for amazon EC2s should be the one provided by Amazon only we cant download from microsoft and use the trial versions directly.

Hence we saw the errors. When we use the image from amazon public snapshot - windows server version, it starts to work.